# SELECT all rows that contain a URL

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say table:

**comments**: *id, id_user, content, date*

Where content can contain html code, so it can contain images.

So how can i select all the rows from comments table that contain images? ( `<img src="image.png" />` )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE content LIKE '%<img%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the like condition:

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE content LIKE '%<img src="%" />%';
```

Comment: that's the thing, i don't know what images might be

Comment: Updated my answer, you just need to set three "wildcards" (%) there.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= '%%'' at line 1

Comment: The image is not always the same syntax. Can have an alt/title or sizes attributes.

Comment: I copied and pasted the query, and no. the image doesn't allways have size, title or alt attributes

Comment: @Siva, my bad, I already removed it (thanks for pointing that out). Fratyr, I just search for what you indicated on your answer, you can check Paul's Grimshaw answer bellow, it will detect any image, this is just a way to do it, you need to adapt it to your needs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions in your query:
http://www.brightcherry.co.uk/scribbles/mysql-how-to-count-a-regular-expression-in-a-table-column/

Comment: Can you elaborate? this looks more like a comment

Comment: Sorry, I thought it will go directly to comments :(

Comment: May that be a good start to you? http://www.brightcherry.co.uk/scribbles/mysql-how-to-count-a-regular-expression-in-a-table-column/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with regular expressions you can do it like:

```
select * from comments where content regexp'<img'
```